# How to write query with time between now and midnight of today in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have query like below

```
SELECT * FROM programs where startTime between now() and now() + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Is it possible to write query with time between now and midnight of today in MySQL?

Something like below

```
SELECT * FROM programs where startTime between now() and now() + midnight 12;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suggest you always use clopen (closed-open) intervals for dates and times comparisons. `BETWEEN` means closed intervals (from both sides). A very good explanation is in [@Aaron Bertrand's](https://stackexchange.com/users/24165/aaron-bertrand?tab=accounts) blog post: **[What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)**. Here's a way to write the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM programs 
WHERE startTime >= NOW() 
  AND startTime < CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY ;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * FROM programs where startTime between now() and CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Current date returns the beginning of the day, then we add 1 day to get to the end of it.

Comment: This will include `00:00:00` of tomorrow; it's unclear whether that's desirable.

Comment: Yes, you probably want to use `where startTime >= now() and startTime < CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
SELECT * FROM programs where startTime between now() and DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: This is not correct syntax, you need one more argument to `between`

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following: May be it's long though.

**Sample Table:**

```
ID  STIME                               ETIME
1   December, 05 2012 05:23:00+0000     December, 05 2012 07:30:00+0000
2   December, 05 2012 10:23:00+0000     December, 05 2012 12:30:00+0000
3   December, 06 2012 22:45:00+0000     December, 07 2012 01:00:00+0000
4   December, 06 2012 22:23:00+0000     December, 06 2012 23:55:00+0000
5   December, 06 2012 20:23:00+0000     December, 06 2012 22:55:00+0000
6   December, 07 2012 10:23:00+0000     December, 07 2012 12:30:00+0000
```

**Query**

```
SELECT  *,curtime() FROM prog
WHERE date(stime) = date(now())
AND date(etime) = date(now())
AND time_to_sec(SUBTIME(etime,'24:00:00')) >= 0
;
```

**Results**

```
ID  STIME                               ETIME   
4   December, 06 2012 22:23:00+0000     December, 06 2012 23:55:00+0000     
5   December, 06 2012 20:23:00+0000     December, 06 2012 22:55:00+0000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   programs
WHERE  DATE(startTime) = CURRENT_DATE AND startTime > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```